# Html script scr won't work

Tags: javascript, html

there

I want to add my javascript file onto an html, but when I put

```
<script scr="check.js"></script>
```

The page won't recognise it. But if I add the jQuery file

```
<script scr="jquery-3.1.1.min"></script>
```

it recognises it.

Any ideas of why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: it's `src`, typo probably

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script src="check.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You've got a typo...Just change "scr" to "src".